# Can anyone suggest some web frameworks for database developers?

Tags: sql, web-applications, rdbms

There seems to be a long-standing trend in web development to abstract the database to the point of being a glorified spreadsheet, a simple data dump.

I really like RDBM systems, SQL, and the associated procedural programming.  I think the choice of RDBMS aught to be part of the solution.  MY RDBMS of choice is PostgreSQL and I'd very much like to take advantage of the features of a RDBMS and of postgres' specific features.

I'd like to leverage the DB for things like data integrity.  I'd like to use things like constraints (FK and otherwise), triggers, listen/notify, windowing, stored procedures, and so on.

Basically I want to create a data layer API using PL/PGSQL through which the database is accessed by the web application.  I've already got an authentication and persistent login API, and a Calendar API with full support for iCal-style event repetitions (a pleasant challenge to implement!)

What I'd like is a framework that enables this kind of DB-oriented development, heavy on stored procedures.  That doesn't get in the way of the DB, but makes it easy to proxy data to and from the client.

Ideally, I'd like something that doesn't have a lot of boilerplate code for executing queries (if at all.)  Something that could take HTTP GET/POST data for query parameters, then return query results to the client in JSON or XML.  Light-weight, asynchronous.  I don't even need html templates - I'm hoping to build the client entirely out of "static" html and javascript.

Note that I'm a fairly versed developer; I just happen to be a fan of relational databases.  I'm willing to admit that my perception of web frameworks and databases might be out of tune!  But that's why I'm here - my perception is fairly entrenched so I'd like to poll the pros.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two things

1) For database access you should looks into [Spring JDBC templates](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html).

2) To do a simple Query to your service with GET, POST, PUT etc methods you should look into RESTful webservices here [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/)